# After marriage, why does the ladies have to follow the man's customs?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, brahmins, smarta

This is a general query for which I just want to understand the fundamental reason why after the marriage of a man and a woman (as per Hindu traditions - More specifically Brahmin traditions), the woman needs to follow the rituals and procedures of the man's family? And why should the girl come to the man's place and why is it not the other way round?

P.S. I apologize for asking such an ignorant question. Just curious to get some answers which I might not have thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the woman needs to follow the rituals and procedures of the man's family?`

Not completely true. In the commentary on the SaptapadikaraNa ritual in the Wedding rituals, Sri Mukkur Lakshminarasimhacharya states on the mantra of third step (in the 7 steps) `trINi vratAya viShNu tvAnvetu` - `With the third step, I pray that we be well established in vratas. May Vishnu accompany you/us.

Here, the author says that the wife should not only follow the customs of her in-laws home but also bring in new customs from her home and should result in a following of a larger number of vratas than in either home.

I realize that sometimes customs conflict. What to do in the case of a conflict is a different issue. Broadly speaking, there should be a (mathematical) union of the two sets of customs post wedding.